# Add key to dict with setattr() in Python

Tags: python

How can I add a key to an object's dictionary with `setattr()`? Say I have the `fields` dictionary defined in my class. From another class I would like to add a key to this dictionary. How do I proceed? `setattr(cls, 'fields', 'value')` changes the attribute entirely.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't, if you need to go down the name lookup route, then you use:

```
getattr(cls, 'fields')['key'] = 'value'
```

Comment: Haven't thought about this. Thank you!

Comment: Can't use assignment in lambda.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getattr` instead of `setattr` to do this. Something like.

```
>>> class TestClass:
        def __init__(self):
            self.testDict = {}


>>> m = TestClass()
>>> m.testDict
{}
>>> getattr(m, "testDict")["key"] = "value"
>>> m.testDict
{'key': 'value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `cls.fields['key'] = 'value'`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't need `setattr()` to add a new key value pair into a dictionary like attribute.

All you need is:

```py
obj.dictionary_name[key] = value
# type(key) : str
```

Although if you intend to use `setattr()` due to some reason, you can use:

```py
getattr(obj,"dictionary_name")[key] = value
```

Advantage being you can use this in a setter or in some class method along with some code, whereas in the earlier method you cannot.

Although I found great use of this when I had to do something like this:

```py
obj.f"_{dictionary_name}[{key}]" = value
```

For a fact it's known you cannot use string to access instance attribute.

So I tried:

```py
setattr(obj,f"_{dictionary_name}[{key}]",value)
# this creates a new instance attribute.
# assume dictionary_name is example, key is color and value is red
# obj.__dict__ will contain '_example[color]' : 'red' instead of '_example' : {'color' : 'red'}
```

Here is the fix:

```py
getattr(obj,f"_{dictionary_name}")[key] = value
```